# Are FFMPEG, Imageshack Included on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I'm finally setting up my own server for my two websites and I'd like to know what image and video applications are included in Ubuntu server, such as FFMPEG, Imagemagick, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No Image and Video applications are included in Ubuntu Server, but I don't think it would be wise to have them on a server anyway. Uses up resources, you know?

But, if you feel so inclined, you can install them, I think.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick